# Array of subclasses and onClick()

Tags: android

I want to create by code an array of objects that are subclasses of Button.

```
public class MyButton extends Button {
    private Context ctx;
    private int status;
    public MyButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        ctx = context;
        status = 0;
    }

    private click() {
        status = 1;
        // OTHER CODE THAT NEEDS TO STAY HERE
    }
}
```

In the main activity I do this:

```
public class myActivity extends Activity {
    private MyButton[] myButtons = new MyButton[100];

    @Override
    public onCreate(Bundle si) {
         super.onCreate(si);
         createButtons();
    }

    private void createButtons() {
         for (int w=0; w<100; w++) {
             myButtons[w] = new MyButton(myActivity.this);
             myButtons[w].setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener() {
                  public void onClick(View v) {
                  // ... (A)
                  }
             });
         }
    }
}
```

Now I want the click() method inside MyButton to be run each time the button is clicked.
Seems obvious but it is not at my eyes.

If I make the click() method public and run it directly from (A), I get an error because myButtons[w].click() is not static and cannot be run from there.

In the meantime, I an not able to understand where to put the code in the MyButton class to intercept a click and run click() from there. Should I override onClick? Or should I override onClickListener? Or what else should I do?

How can I run click() whenever one of myButtons[] object is clicked?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add:

```
View.onClickListener onclick = new View.onClickListener() {
                  public void onClick(View v) {
                     ((MyButton)v).click();
                     //since v should be instance of MyButton
                  }
             };
```

to your Activity
then use:

```
myButtons[w].setOnClickListener(onclick); 
//one instance of onclick is enough, there is no need to create it for every button
```

in createButtons()

but ... why, oh why array of buttons we have ListView in android ...

Answer (score 2):

You can cast `View v` you got in listener to `MyButton` and call `click` on it:

```
private void createButtons() {
    View.OnClickListener listener = new View.onClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ((MyButton) v).click();
        }
     };
     for (int w=0; w<100; w++) {
         myButtons[w] = new MyButton(myActivity.this);
         myButtons[w].setOnClickListener(listener);
     }
}
```